# You can't specify target table 'b' for update in FROM clause

Tags: mysql

I need to know where did i do wrong in this sql statement. I try to find solution in previous threads with similar problem but none can solve my problem. so i think maybe my statement is actually wrong.

```
UPDATE table1 b

LEFT JOIN table2 m ON b.ICNO=m.ICNO

SET b.SalMoveMth = '01'

WHERE
    m.Status!='6' AND 
    (DATE_FORMAT(startDateSand,'%m')='10' OR DATE_FORMAT(startDateSand,'%m')='11' OR 
        DATE_FORMAT(startDateSand,'%m')='12') AND 
    ((SELECT SalMoveMth FROM table1 WHERE ICNO=table2.ICNO ORDER BY SalMoveMthStDt DESC LIMIT 1)!='10').
```

Thank You.

Comment: what actually is your problem? Which is the error message?

Answer (score 0):

last part of the where clause:

instead of :

```
where ICNO=table2.ICNO order by SalMoveMthStDt desc limit 1)!='10')
```

try:

```
where ICNO=table2.ICNO order by SalMoveMthStDt desc limit 1)<>'10')
```

also :

```
and b.SalMoveMth in (
((select SalMoveMth from table1 where ICNO=table2.ICNO order by 
SalMoveMthStDt desc limit 1)<>'10'))
```

Comment: still get the same error. is it because of the nested query? any solution for that?

Comment: can u script your 2 tables and some data that u have on it and send me plz?

Answer (score 0):

```
update table1 
set SalMoveMth = '01' where icno in 
  (select b.ICNO from table1 b 
   left join table2 m on b.ICNO=m.ICNO
   where m.Status!='6' 
   and (DATE_FORMAT(startDateSand,'%m')='10' or 
        DATE_FORMAT(startDateSand,'%m')='11' or 
        DATE_FORMAT(startDateSand,'%m')='12') 
   and b.SalMoveMth in (
     ((select SalMoveMth 
       from table1 
       where ICNO=table2.ICNO 
       order by SalMoveMthStDt desc limit 1)<>'10')
  )
```